# Tooltip culture is wrong

Tags: c#, wpf, number-formatting

I have in xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{local:Bind Test}" ToolTip="{local:Bind Test}" />
```

And here is screenshot (using magnifier):

[image]

My question is what is going on here? Why tooltip displays value differently (decimal point is `.` while `,` is expected)?

---

Longer story:

I am trying to display numbers in same format as in user Windows number format preferences.

For this I've override the language before displaying window (overriding App.OnStartup):

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

And using following custom binding (to set converter culture by default)

```
public class Bind : Binding
{
    public Bind(string path) : base(path)
    {
        ConverterCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    }
}
```

It works for `Text` property of `TextBox`, but it doesn't work for `ToolTip`.

To actually see what I show on screenshot:

- go (Windows 7) `Control Panel/Region and Language/Formats` and set `Format` as `English (United States)`
- go `Additional settings/Numbers` and change `Decimal symbol` from `.` to `,`
- create new wpf application, copy xaml, add language override, add converter and set:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public double Test { get; set; } = 1.234567;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also facing the same problem. So you can resolve this by adding `TextBlock` inside the `ToolTip` and bind the same `Text="{local:Bind Test}"` for this ToolTip's TextBlock also.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock Text="{local:Bind Test}"/>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Same result. I am not changing `CurrentCulture` or `CurrentUICulture` (both having `,` as number decimal point). The point is why `ToolTip` doesn't use it. I can change it to have some *exotic* separator, like `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-Ru") { NumberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = "+" } };` (prior overriding language), that works for `Text` without problem, but is ignored by `ToolTip`.

Comment: @Sinatr Yes, i'm also facing the same problem. so you can resolve this by adding TextBlock inside the tooltip and bind the same Text="{local:Bind Test}" for this ToolTip's TextBlock also.



<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>    
        <TextBlock Text="{local:Bind Test}"/>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>

Comment: Great idea (to put `TextBlock` inside `TextBlock.ToolTip`), add this to the answer and I'll accept it.