# Setting ConverterCulture using x:Static

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to fix one issue and suddenly this:

---

[image]

---

What is wrong? It's compilable and seems to work at run-time without problems. Restarting VS doesn't help, xaml designer say "Invalid markup" all time.

---

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:SystemGlobalization="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test, ConverterCulture={x:Static SystemGlobalization:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}" />
</Window>
```

Compiler error:

> The member "CurrentCulture" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Some more details:

- VS 2015
- .Net Framework 4.5

Comment: Please see the post: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477598/the-member-currentculture-is-not-recognized-or-is-not-accessible

Comment: Works for me, no errors in VS2010 or VS2013

Comment: @MartinPrediger, thanks for finding duplicate, but it doesn't have accepted solution and none of answers helps, e.g. I must target `4.5` and I am trying to switch from custom binding to xaml earlier because of [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37182987/1997232).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Sinatr, CurrentCulture is a read only property. so you can use

```
Text="{Binding Test,ConverterCulture={x:Static SystemGlobalization:CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture}}"
```

Comment: I needed to set value to DefaultThreadCurrentCulture on App.cs (was null)
just added : `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;`
 under app.cs c'tor